# MySQL - Too big `.idb` file for an empty table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using `innodb_file_per_table`, and MySQL creates an `.idb` file for each individual table.

The problem is that `.idb` files are pretty big (several giga bytes) for empty tables.

I am using these tables as a temporary storage. For some reason, I insert hundreds of thousands of records to these tables every day, process them, move them to another database, and delete records that are processed.

Could this be a reason behind why `.idb` file is very file, even if an underlying table contains no records? If so, do I need to run `optimize table table_name` periodically? Is there any other way to shrink `.idb` files?

Comment: Use `TRUNCATE tablename` as an efficient way to empty a table, rather than deleting rows.

Comment: @Barmar, I cannot use `TRUNCATE` command, because I need to delete only rows that meet a certain criteria, rather than deleting all rows, emptying an table.

Comment: Since the Question mentioned "empty", Truncate is an obvious suggestion.  Adel, please provide more details on the lifetime of rows in your table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to shrink an InnoDB tablespace file, either the system tablespace (`ibdata1`) or the file-per-table tablespaces or general tablespaces (which may contain multiple tables).

But what you can do is *copy* the remaining data (if any) to a new tablespace, and then new tablespace replaces the old one, which is then deleted.

You can delete all data in one table in one atomic operation using `TRUNCATE TABLE`. You can defragment all data in one table and copy it to new pages using `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE <tablename> FORCE`.

In the case of a file-per-table tablespace, these operations also accomplish the steps of copying the table to a new tablespace and dropping the old tablespace. The new tablespace is sized only as large as needed to store the data that was copied.

In the case of the system tablespace or general tablespaces, TRUNCATE TABLE or OPTIMIZE TABLE don't do this. They move data around to new pages within the tablespace, which may actually *expand* the tablespace. Then the old pages are marked free, so they may be reused by other data eventually.